# How to open nwjs app in sdk version to debug?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nwjs

I'm finding it hard to run the nwjs app in sdk version
in project terminal if we run

```
nw
```

usually it opens nw app but in normal version

I want to use [debugging tools](https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Debugging%20with%20DevTools/) and it only works in sdk version. I know to open manually ie. if we drag the project folder to nw.exe means it opens in sdk mode.

I wonder if there is any code or command line prompt to open it

i tried running the nw command and it opened in normal version
I want to run the nwjs app in sdk version using terminal or cmd

Answer (score 0):

Run `/path/to/sdk/nw.exe .` when you're in the project directory containing `package.json`.

Comment: thanks for the response @sysrage

i tried running the command "nw.exe ."

I get the following error,

nw.exe : The term 'nw.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nw.exe .
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nw.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You got that error because you didn’t provide the full path to `nw.exe` like I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

the following thing worked for me.

in the project folder update the package.json as,

```
{
 "name": "appName",
 "main": "index.html",
 "scripts": {
    "manual": "nw .",
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "nw": "0.82.0-sdk"
  },
"engines": {
"node": "v20.5.0",
"npm": "9.8.0"
  },
"packageManager": "npm@9.8.0",
}
```

now run the script in command prompt as,

> npm run manual

This should open your app in nwjs sdk mode :)